# Getting number of child from particular node in firebase real time DB

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I am relatively new in firebase admin and node js.

My structure is like this.

[image]

I just want to count total number in "Message". How shall I do?

```
exports.getStat = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

    return Promise.all([
        admin.database().ref(`/Message`).once('value')])            
            .then(response => {
    return res.send({"message": Object.keys(response).length});
});

});
```

Comment: Your strategy here involves reading the *entire* contents of Messages on every request just to get the count.  That's potentially very expensive, and slow if the number of children is large.  Consider instead keeping track of a count in another node.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TPKA88_FmkA&index=2&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLnJVX_0zbKytptZGugPIbJR

Comment: set a cloudfunctions that will update the countLenght OnUpdate of Message node. Then you will only need to read this value instead of processing everytime the count.